# How to prove that the set $e^{inx}$ is closed with respect to this measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Why is the set $\{e^{inx}\}$ closed in $L^2(d\nu)$, where $d\nu(x)=(1+|h(x)|)dx+|ds(x)|$?
$d\nu$ is defined in this proof I am struggling to understand, where $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure on $[-\pi,\pi]$, for which $d\mu(x)=h(x)dx+ds(x)$. This should be because od Lebesgue-Radon-Nykodym, so $s$ is singular and $h\in L^1$.

I was also wondering how does $\nu$ look like? It should be that $(1+|h(x)|)dx$ is $d\nu$'s  absolutely continuous part with respect to Lebesgue measure and that $|ds(x)|$ is $d\nu$'s singular part (with respect to Lebesgue measure). But can we reconstruct $\nu$ from this?

Comment: What is $h$? Can you give a link to the proof you are struggling to understand?

Answer (score 1):

No matter what the function $h$ is, the measure $\nu$ is greater than Lebesgue measure, so convergence in $L^2(\nu)$ implies convergence in $L^2(dx)$. Now, the functions $e_n(x)=e^{inx}$ are orthogonal and normalized in $L^2(dx)$, so if $(n_k)$ is a sequence of integers such that the sequence $(e_{n_k})$ is convergent in $L^2(dx)$, then in fact the sequence $(n_k)$ is eventually constant. Therefore, if $(e_{n_k})$ is convergent in $L^2(\nu)$, then $(n_k)$ is eventually constant and hence the limit function is one of the $e_n$'s.